# Question on TSQL conversion to date from character string error

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 columns that contain YEAR, MONTH and DAY VARCHAR data type values.  When I try to CONCATENATE these columns and CONVERT or CAST to a DATE data type I get an error. I've been googling this afternoon and trying different solutions but to no avail.  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

The error I'm getting is:
**Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 120
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Here is my code:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.AccountNumber, t.Birthday, t.DOBSource
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbyear' THEN a01c.CodeValue ELSE NULL END) AS bYR
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbmonth' THEN a01c.CodeValue ELSE NULL END) AS bMO
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbday' THEN CASE WHEN LEN(a01c.CodeValue) = 1 THEN CONCAT('0', a01c.CodeValue) ELSE a01c.CodeValue END END) AS bDY
FROM dbo.sA01cAccountCodes A01C (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BGTEMP.dbo.tmp22189_FirstPass t
ON a01c.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber 
WHERE A01C.CodeType IN ('ddcbyear', 'ddcbmonth', 'ddcbday')
AND A01C.CodeValue NOT LIKE '%/%'
AND A01C.Active = 1
AND (t.Birthday IS NULL
    AND t.DOBSource IS NULL)
--AND t.AccountNumber = 405630011
GROUP BY t.AccountNumber, t.Birthday, t.DOBSource
--253802
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Birthday = CAST(c.bMO + '/' + c.bDY + '/' + c.bYR AS DATE)  --this is a DATE data type column
    , t.DOBSource = 'A01c'
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN BGTEMP.dbo.tmp22189_FirstPass t
ON c.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber
WHERE (c.bYR IS NOT NULL
    AND c.bMO IS NOT NULL
    AND c.bDY IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Other issues aside, when working with dates in SQL Server you are safest using unambiguous ISO YYYYMMDD format

Comment: If I were given this problem, I'd first validate the concatenated date expression you are CASTing is what you're expecting just by doing a select from CTE. If it's not a valid m/d/y expression, then CAST/CONVERT isn't where your problem is.

Comment: @NeilMoss, I did as you stated and what is displayed is a valid yyyy-mm-dd expression when just executing a select.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to use the 'YYYY-MM-DD' when concatenating the date parts

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.AccountNumber, t.Birthday, t.DOBSource
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbyear' THEN a01c.CodeValue ELSE NULL END) AS bYR
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbmonth' THEN a01c.CodeValue ELSE NULL END) AS bMO
    , MAX(CASE WHEN a01c.CodeType = 'ddcbday' THEN CASE WHEN LEN(a01c.CodeValue) = 1 THEN CONCAT('0', a01c.CodeValue) ELSE a01c.CodeValue END END) AS bDY
FROM dbo.sA01cAccountCodes A01C (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BGTEMP.dbo.tmp22189_FirstPass t
ON a01c.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber 
WHERE A01C.CodeType IN ('ddcbyear', 'ddcbmonth', 'ddcbday')
AND A01C.CodeValue NOT LIKE '%/%'
AND A01C.Active = 1
AND (t.Birthday IS NULL
    AND t.DOBSource IS NULL)
--AND t.AccountNumber = 405630011
GROUP BY t.AccountNumber, t.Birthday, t.DOBSource
--253802
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Birthday = CAST(c.bYR + '-' + c.bMO + '-' + c.bDY AS DATE)  --this is a DATE data type column, now using 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
    , t.DOBSource = 'A01c'
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN BGTEMP.dbo.tmp22189_FirstPass t
ON c.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber
WHERE (c.bYR IS NOT NULL
    AND c.bMO IS NOT NULL
    AND c.bDY IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did NOT work.  I still get the same error. I entered In the SET t.Birthday = CAST(CONCAT(c.bYR,'-',c.bMO,'-',c.bMO) AS DATE).  I also tried using CONVERT instead of cast and still got the same error.

Comment: Have you followed the advice of Stu and Neil? Show as what you get

Comment: Horaciux, yes I did but unfortunately it did not work.  Thanks for everyone's time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CAST, try CONVERT instead and use a style specifier. It takes out any guesswork regarding regional settings or SQL server date format (dmy/mdy) settings.

Try the style specifier 23, meaning ISO8601, accepting a string in format yyyy-mm-dd.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your time in responding.  In the SELECT after the CTE, I revised the code as follows:
SELECT c.AccountNumber, c.Birthday, c.DOBSource, c.bYR, c.bMO, c.bDY, CONVERT(DATE, c.DOB, 101) AS DOB
but unfortunately that gave me the same error.

Comment: How do you construct c.DOB? Make sure that it has leading zeroes on month and days.

Comment: I used CONCAT to construct the c.DOB in the CTE portion of the code.  I did make sure that there is a leading 0 in the months and days.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY found the issue with the CONVERT and/or CAST to the date data type.  In the MONTH and DAY columns the value was '00' and NOT a valid numeric value for month or day.  Consequently the conversion would NOT work.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. My first comment applied :-)

Answer (score 0):

[DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) assumes numeric inputs. You would have to cast the numeric strings back to integers first.

Answer (score -1):

What version of SQL are you working with? If  you have SQL 2012 and later, use the DATEFROMPARTS() function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I did try DATEFROMPARTS but I got the same error.  Thanks.